# How to fit 10 speed cassette on this hub

Tags: shimano, cassette, hub

I bought a pair of Mach 1 wheels from PlanetX that said the hub was compatible with Shimano 8/9/10 speed. When I tried to install my 10 speed Tiagra 4700 cassette it doesn't seem to go down far enough on the hub. PlanetX just said if it doesn't fit you can return it but should it not fit? It looks like it should but maybe I'm missing something?

https://www.planetx.co.uk/i/q/WPMNEOD/mach-1-neo-disc-rims-on-6-bolt-9mm-quick-release-28-hole-disc-hubs
[image: stock photo of hub]

[image: my cassette sitting too high]
[image: gap underneath my cassette]
[image: top of cassette without the locknut showing it sitting too high for nut to catch the hub]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "doesn't seem to go down far enough on the hub"?  You can always expect the cassette to protrude a little bit over the edge of the hub.  This is so that when you tighten it, the cassette is held firmly in place.

Comment: I've added photos to illustrate it better @RoKa

Comment: I assume that the lock ring is not grabbing threads?

Comment: Yeah, that's right @NateWengert

Comment: I've heard of those Tiagra 4600s having some compatibility issues with some 8/9/10sp hubs, where they wont fit but a 105 or Ultegra 10sp does, let me see if i can find anymore details on it, i assume that there is not a spacer stuck to the back? ;)

Comment: Yeah, no spacer on the back @NateWengert

Comment: Are the splines smooth, no barbs?

Comment: How does the old cassette compare when fitted?  Does the gap between the spokes and cassette look about the same?  Your picture looks like its not on far enough, so my eye,

Comment: For anyone wondering how this was solved the answer was brute force. A good shove from a friend and it went all the way down :)

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced this exact problem except trying to fit a 4600 cassette on the same hub.

If you look at the cone, you will notice the threads expand slightly nearer the centre at the point at which they start to stick.

I will update this answer if I ever get a clear explanation for this design feature.

Update​: lbs got it on with some brute force! Presumably a one way road? Will update if it goes badly wrong.